# A differential-functional equation: $f'(f^{-1}(x)) = 1/g(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

**Problem**:

> Given $g(x)$, solve the equation $f'(f^{-1}(x)) = \frac{1}{g(x)}$ for an invertible and differentiable function $f(x)$.

So far I have tried setting $y = f^{-1}(x) \Leftrightarrow x = f(y)$, obtaining the differential equation
$$
f'(y) = \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{g(x)}
$$

which we then solve to obtain $y$ in terms of $x$, i.e. to obtain the inverse function $f^{-1}(x)$. If this is easily inverted then we can find $f(x)$.

What I am interested in is if anyone knows a better way to solve this, desirably one which allows us to determine $f(x)$ directly.

I'm new to this kind of equation so please correct me if there's a better term for it than "differential-functional" :)

**Edit:**
I probably should say that in the particular context I am considering, $g(x)$ is the norm of a non-zero vector $\vec{r}(x)$ and is hence always positive.

Answer (score 2):

Chen, let $h=f^{-1}.$ Multiply both sides by $h'$ to get $(f'h)h'=h'/g.$ But observe that $f'(f^{-1}(x))(f^{-1})'(x)=(f\circ f^{-1})'(x)=1.$ Hence, we have $(f^{-1})'(x)=g(x).$  So, $f^{-1}(x)=\int_0^x g(t) dt$..

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that's the same result I got as posted in the question, just obtained using a different method.

Comment: @Josh: I upvoted your comment, but this answer does show that if $g(t)\gt 0$ there is an inverse, which your question does not make explicit.

Comment: Josh:No, they are not the same.  However, one should be more careful, for instance, i am multiplying both sides by $f^{-1}(x)$ which means that I am assuming it is not zero, also as noted by Josh, integral of g increasing..etc

Comment: @Ross: Sorry I can't see how $g(x)>0$ implies the existence of an inverse. Could you explain? But it was helpful you mentioned this because in the particular context I am looking at this problem, $g(x)$ _is_ always positive - in fact it's a norm of a vector. So if I understood you correctly this would mean that the equation always has a solution $f(x)$?

Comment: @niyazi: I'm going to be a bit of a pain and ask you elaborate on the "integral of g increasing.." part. Thanks :)

Comment: @Eelvex: I reverted your edits because (a) the notation you choose is unfortunate: to minimize confusion, as a matter of style, you should not write $(\int g(x) dx)^{-1}(x)$ (b) your use of the indefinite integral is not really an improvement: it is better to just remark that in the last line of niyazi's answer there should be an implicit $+C$.